# Unable to connect to MySQL from C#

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

update: I have connect my provider and it turns out that servers are blocked firewall, we can only use a php connection string script like this

```
$db=mysql_connect("yourdomain.com.mysql", "username", "password"); mysql_select_db("database", $db);
```

is there anyway i can connect the database now? with a c# form application

Im unable to connect to mysql, I get error 1042 using MySql.Data.dll version 6.4

this is which I use to connect to server

```
string  myConnectionString = "server=mydata_net;uid=mydata_net;pwd=test21;database=myweb.net;";
try
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("OK");
    conn.Close();
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    switch (ex.Number)
    {
        case 0:
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
            break;
        case 1042:
            MessageBox.Show("Can't get hostname address");
            break;
        case 1045:
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `myweb.net.mysql` resolve from the computer running this code? Can you ping it?

Comment: database=myweb.net? server=mydata_net? Are you sure?

Comment: Can you connect using the command-line client from the same machine? What exact error do you get (can you inspect the Exception object?)? What do you see when you look at the network traffic with Wireshark? Does the above code work in your development environment?

Comment: Also host names with underscores in them aren't legal in DNS. However this doesn't ever seem to have stopped Windows (NT etc) admins using them anyway.

Comment: sorry it should be the same. but still not working

Comment: Now I see you've changed the db's name at the conn-string to "database=myweb.net". I think you smoke too much buddy (: ................ As answered already - make sure the 'server' part of the conn-string points to the server for real, otherwise, if it doesn't point to the mysql server you'll get a "Can't get hostname address" error!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you change 'mydata_net' to 'myweb.net' at the 'myConnectionString' and you'll be fine.

It's a simple typo.

Edit:

```
myConnectionString = "server=mydata_net;uid=mydata_net;" +
            "pwd=test21;database=myweb_net;";
```

should become

```
myConnectionString = "server=myweb.net;uid=mydata_net;" +
            "pwd=test21;database=myweb_net;";
```

Comment: Are you sure you've replaced the string and its parameters are ALL correct? (it's actually only about the server's address, i.e a DNS problem). Look, as Oded suggested, try pinging from the computer which runs the above code to the server. i.e "ping myweb.net". If you don't get a reply then it means you're pointing at the wrong direction.